# How do I get value of a nav-parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Well I'am creating DB in SQLite, using the ionic framework.
My question is how i get nav-parameter?

Here's my main page :

[image]

Here's it's html:

```
<ion-content nopadding>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let processo of processos; let i = index">
      <button ion-item (click)="editarProcesso(processo.id)">
          <p>{{ processo.id }}</p>
          <h2> {{ processo.processoNumero}} </h2>
          <p>{{ processo.data }} {{ processo.horaInicio }}</p>
      </button>
      <ion-item-options side="left">
        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="removeProcesso(processo)"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
      </ion-item-options>
```

Here's the ts

```
editarProcesso(id){
this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {
  id : id
});return console.log('id: ',id);}
```

Here's the provider

```
public getcamposProcesso(id: number) {
return this.dbProvider.getDB()
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    let sql = 'Select * From Processos WHERE id = ?';
    let data = [id];

    return db.executeSql(sql, data)
      .then((data: any) => {
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
          let item = data.rows.item(0);
          let processo = new Processos();
          processo.tribunalDaExecucao = item.tribunalDaExecucao;
          processo.tribunalDeprecado = item.tribunalDeprecado;
          processo.processoNumero = item.processoNumero;
          processo.oficioNumero = item.oficioNumero;
          processo.data = item.data;
          processo.horaInicio = item.horaInicio;
          processo.horaFim = item.horaFim;
          processo.local = item.local;
          processo.aeDesignado = item.aeDesignado;
          processo.aeDiligencia = item.aeDiligencia;
          processo.dividaExequenda = item.dividaExequenda;
          processo.despesasProvaveis = item.despesasProvaveis;
          processo.depositario = item.depositario;
          processo.localDeposito = item.localDeposito;


          return processo;
        }

        return null;
      })
      .catch((e) => console.error(e));
  })
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

}

Nevertheless this how try to get my parameter:

```
constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
public navParams: NavParams,
  private platform: Platform,
  private sqlite: SQLite,
  private dbProvider: DatabaseProvider,
  private processoProvider : ProcessosProvider,
  private toast: Toast,
  private toastController: ToastController) {

    this.model = new Processos();


      if (this.navParams.data.id){
      this.processoProvider.getcamposProcesso(this.navParams.data.id)
      .then((result : any) =>{
        this.model = result;
        return console.log(this.navParams.data.id);
      }).catch((e) => console.log('Erro ao carregar os campos', e))
    }


  }
```

Here is the console log mensage, of when i click in ion item with data in it, the result of id it's from script below the HTML and null it's from the last script, where i show how i get my parameter.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which page are you accessing id? you are sending to HomePage... but your ionViewDidLoad log says a different page

Comment: Actually a think that's why give a sec.

Comment: Could you see the new log post.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure you are getting the id in your below function.

```
editarProcesso(id){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {id : id});
}
```

then try to fetch that id using below method in your home page.

```
let id = this.navParams.get('id');
```

Comment: I already know my problem, sending the parameters do the wrong page.

Comment: Do you know any way of something like this, this.navCtrl.push( HomePage, DadosPrincipaisPage , { id: id});?

Comment: So, it seems like you want to pass the same parameter to multiple pages. It that is the case then, you can do it this way.
1. Pass id to Homepage. 
2. Retrieve id in Homepage and again send id in DadosPrincipaisPage.
3. Retrieve id in DadosPrincipaisPage.

Comment: and how would i send to the DadosPrincipaisPage

Comment: same way as you are passing to the Homepage. But you have to make sure you have value in your id variable.

 this.navCtrl.push(DadosPrincipaisPage, {id : id});

Comment: Or i'am really wrong, navCtrl.push sends to a page x, if i do that i only would receive a design of the page x not page x inside the page y

Comment: Please refer below link to add/remove the page in ionic. I think it would be beneficial for you to understand page navigation first.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/Nav/

Comment: I can' t do like that, because I use SuperTabs, anyways i already resolved i emit an event from ionic native

Answer (score -1):

in home.ts declare **id** and call **this.id**

```
export class HomePage {
id: any = '0';

constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
public navParams: NavParams,
  private platform: Platform,
  private sqlite: SQLite,
  private dbProvider: DatabaseProvider,
  private processoProvider : ProcessosProvider,
  private toast: Toast,
  private toastController: ToastController)
```

and add this :

```
this.id = navParams.get('id');
```

Comment: i must fecth my id from the ion item that i clicked